# Using matplotlib colorbar/colorbarbase with point data

Tags: python, matplotlib

So i need to create 2D plot with set points an colour them using "z axis" values, like this as you can see that's not a problem.

[image: plot]

what i need now is to add colorbar on the right with full color scale. i've tried to do this but to no  effect  :<
here's my code

```
x=numpy.loadtxt('h2o.dat',unpack=True)
shiftposition(x,-45.1*prze,266.67)
vmin=x[0].min()
vmax=x[0].max()
dv=vmax-vmin

cmap = cm.jet
colors = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin+0.0, vmax+0.0)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.arrow(-46,345, 100*math.sin(math.radians(40)), 100*math.cos(math.radians(40)), head_width=20, head_length=20, fc='r', ec='r',color='r')
plt.arrow(25,163, 100*math.sin(math.radians(125)), 100*math.cos(math.radians(125)), head_width=20, head_length=20, fc='r', ec='r',color='r')
plt.arrow(-280,342, 100*math.sin(math.radians(-55)), 100*math.cos(math.radians(-55)), head_width=20, head_length=20, fc='b', ec='b',color='b')
plt.arrow(-233,120, 100*math.sin(math.radians(-140)), 100*math.cos(math.radians(-140)), head_width=20, head_length=20, fc='b', ec='b',color='b')

plt.scatter(-20*prze,242.8,marker='+',s=50,color='k')
ax.scatter(x[1],x[2],marker='^',color=cm.jet((x[0]-vmin)/dv,1),s=50,zorder=3)
cax = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax,  cmap=cmap,norm=colors,orientation='vertical',spacing='uniform',ticklocation='auto')
ax.set_xlim(-500,250)
ax.set_ylim(-200,550)
ax.invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

all i get is this:
[image: fail :<]

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `plt.colorbar` function, http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html

Comment: I feel like you're not adding the colorbar to your plot. `fig.colorbar(args)`

Comment: if i understand correctly plt.colorbar is for image and contour plots that are ScalarMappable and it's not usefull in my case.. and colorbar.ColorbarBase should be more universal but it don't work for me and i don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you set the `cmap` of scatter, and set the color to the array of values, rather than the call to the colormap that you have now.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=y=z=np.linspace(0,10,11)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

p=ax.scatter(x,y,c=z,cmap='viridis',marker='^',edgecolor='None',s=200)

fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For your example, I guess something like this should do it:

```
p = ax.scatter(x[1],x[2],marker='^',color=(x[0]-vmin)/dv,s=50,zorder=3,cmap='jet')
fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)
```